# Помогите решить пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                      function cheangeAb(){
                        if(top.ab == true){
                          top.ab = false;
                          document.getElementById(\'ABColors\').color = \'#CC0000\';
                        }else if(top.ab == false){
                          top.ab = true;
                          document.getElementById(\'ABColors\').color = \'#00CC00\';
                        }
                      }
                      function cheangeRek(){
                        if(top.rek == true){
                          top.rek = false;
                          document.getElementById(\'REKColors\').color = \'#CC0000\';
                        }else if(top.rek == false){
                          top.rek = true;
                          document.getElementById(\'REKColors\').color = \'#00CC00\';
                          top.AutoReklam();
                        }
                      }
                      function cheangePrims(){
                        if(top.prims == true){
                          top.prims = false;
                          document.getElementById(\'PRIMSColors\').color = \'#CC0000\';
                        }else if(top.prims == false){
                          top.prims = true;
                          document.getElementById(\'PRIMSColors\').color = \'#00CC00\';
                        }
                      }
                      document.write(\'<a href="javascript:cheangeAb();"><font color="\'+((top.ab == true)?\'#00CC00\':\'#CC0000\')+\'" id="ABColors"><b>Автобой</b></font></a>\');
                      document.write(\' | \');
                      document.write(\'<a href="javascript:cheangeRek();"><font color="\'+((top.rek == true)?\'#00CC00\':\'#CC0000\')+\'" id="REKColors"><b>Реклама</b></font></a>\');
                      document.write(\' | \');
                      document.write(\'<a href="javascript:cheangePrims();"><font color="\'+((top.prims == true)?\'#00CC00\':\'#CC0000\')+\'" id="PRIMSColors"><b>Приманки</b></font></a>\');
                    </script>
```

Вот такой код не работают кнопки Реклама и приманки,  а автобой работает в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ты зачем экранируешь кавычки(тут должен быть доктор из мема, но дедушки не одобряют), так делать не нужно

На тебе код, который твой же, но нормальный:

```js
function cheangeAb(){
    if(top.ab == true){
        top.ab = false;
        document.getElementById('ABColors').color = '#CC0000';
    }else if(top.ab == false){
        top.ab = true;
        document.getElementById('ABColors').color = '#00CC00';
    }
}

function cheangeRek(){
    if(top.rek == true){
        top.rek = false;
        document.getElementById('REKColors').color = '#CC0000';
    }else if(top.rek == false){
        top.rek = true;
        document.getElementById('REKColors').color = '#00CC00';
        top.AutoReklam();
    }
}

function cheangePrims(){
    if(top.prims == true){
        top.prims = false;
        document.getElementById('PRIMSColors').color = '#CC0000';
    }else if(top.prims == false){
        top.prims = true;
        document.getElementById('PRIMSColors').color = '#00CC00';
    }
}

document.write('<a href="javascript:cheangeAb();"><font color="'+((top.ab == true)?'#00CC00':'#CC0000')+'" id="ABColors"><b>Автобой</b></font></a>');
document.write(' | ');
document.write('<a href="javascript:cheangeRek();"><font color="'+((top.rek == true)?'#00CC00':'#CC0000')+'" id="REKColors"><b>Реклама</b></font></a>');
document.write(' | ');
document.write('<a href="javascript:cheangePrims();"><font color="'+((top.prims == true)?'#00CC00':'#CC0000')+'" id="PRIMSColors"><b>Приманки</b></font></a>');
```

Comment: Ппц из за кавычки с только я думал ))))

Comment: @ForevOFF из-за всех кавычек..)